# regex to capture multiple words

Tags: regex, boost

I want to capture names of all the interfaces below **without** using captures or groups. Is that possible?

```
class AClass implements Interface1, Interface2, Interface3,Interface4
```

I have tried

```
implements(?:.*?,|[[:space:]]+)[[:word:]]+
```

and variations of it but it doesn't seem to work.
Is it possible?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: `(?<=implements)[\w,\h]*` or `implements\s*\K[\w,\h]*`?

Answer (score 0):

I'd not use regular expressions for this.

Assume you want to parse into this data structure:

```
struct ClassDecl {
    std::string name;
    std::vector<std::string> interfaces;
};
```

Using Boost Spirit, let's define a parse rule for identifiers:

```
qi::rule<It, std::string()> ident = qi::alpha >> *(qi::alnum | qi::char_('_'));
```

> That's a lot more accurate than just *"hoping `[[:word:]]+` will do"*.

You can now parse the entire class declaration with just:

```
"class" >> ident >> -("implements" >> (ident % ','))
```

### Full Demo

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c81d0fb3026bed90)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <iostream>

struct ClassDecl {
    std::string name;
    std::vector<std::string> interfaces;
};

ClassDecl parse_class_declaration(std::string const& text) {
    namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
    using It = std::string::const_iterator;

    ClassDecl result;

    qi::rule<It, std::string()> ident = qi::alpha >> *(qi::alnum | qi::char_('_'));

    if (!qi::phrase_parse(
            text.begin(), text.end(), 
            "class" >> ident >> -("implements" >> (ident % ',')),
            qi::space, result.name, result.interfaces))
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("parse_class_declaration");
    }

    return result;
}

int main() {
    for (auto test_case : {
            "class AClass",
            "class BClass implements Interface1",
            "class CClass implements Interface1, Interface2, Interface3,Interface4",
            })
    {
        auto decl = parse_class_declaration(test_case);
        std::cout << "Parsed '" << decl.name << "' implementing " << decl.interfaces.size() << " interfaces\n";

        for (auto& itf: decl.interfaces) {
            std::cout << " - " << itf << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Prints

```
Parsed 'AClass' implementing 0 interfaces
Parsed 'BClass' implementing 1 interfaces
 - Interface1
Parsed 'CClass' implementing 4 interfaces
 - Interface1
 - Interface2
 - Interface3
 - Interface4
```